# Angular clear input with [ngAutonumeric] directive

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

im' working in angular project  where i use reactive forms and i use the [ngAutonumeric] directive for some inputs , my issue is  : i can't clear the input that contains this directive

i have a form group like this :

// other form controls..

```
dataFormGoup : this.fb.group({
        id : [],
        firstanme: [''],
        lasName: [''],
        amount: ['']
})
```

in my html code i have :

```
<input matInput [ngAutonumeric]="{digitGroupSeparator: ' ', decimalCharacter: ',', decimalCharacterAlternative: '.',
                            currencySymbol: '\u00a0€',
                            currencySymbolPlacement: 's',
                            roundingMethod: 'U',
                            minimumValue: '0'
                          }"  formControlName='amount'>
```

and i hvave a function where i want to clear the form group , i use this code that clear all inputs but the input 'amount' still not empty.

this is my code :

```
//some code..

    this.globalForm.get('dataFormGoup').reset();
```

i try also this code but not works

```
this.globalForm.get('dataFormGoup').get('amount').reset();

this.globalForm.get('creditDocumentaireDetailGroup').patchValue({
   amount: ''
});
```

when i remove the directive [ngAutonumeric] my code works good  , do you have any suggestions to resolve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could this somehow be related https://github.com/angularfy/ng-autonumeric/issues/2?

Answer (score -1):

You can't set the value of `ngAutonumeric` input to null and that's what `reset` function does so, basically to clear that input you have to set it's value to `0`.

Example:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  dataFormGoup: any;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.dataFormGoup = this.fb.group({
      id: ['', []],
      firstanme: ['', []],
      lasName: ['', []],
      amount: ['', []]
    })
  }

  clearAmountField() {
    this.dataFormGoup.get('amount').patchValue(0) // this should do the trick.
  }
}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="dataFormGoup">
    <input [ngAutonumeric]="{digitGroupSeparator: ' ', decimalCharacter: ',', decimalCharacterAlternative: '.',
                            currencySymbol: '\u00a0€',
                            currencySymbolPlacement: 's',
                            roundingMethod: 'U',
                            minimumValue: '0'}" formControlName='amount'>
    <input formControlName='id' placeholder="id" >
    <input formControlName='firstanme' placeholder="firstanme" >
    <input formControlName='lasName' placeholder="lasName" >
</form>

<button (click)="clearAmountField()">clear</button>
```

Comment: Hello @Ahmed thank you for your response, but the patchvalu(0) not working.